# Detect angular2 page refresh

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, page-refresh

Simple question.

I have an angular2 application.

How do I detect if user refreshes the page through the typescript component.

PS: I couldn't make it working through `onbeforeunload`.

Comment: I  tried window.onbeforeunload = function () {
   
}; in a script tag on index.html page. But doen't seem to be working.

Comment: What does "doesn't seem to be working" mean exactly?

Answer (score 2):

Given that Typescript is just a superset of Javascript... if you can't do it in javascript without the Window events, you probably can't do it in Typescript without the Window events. At least, I don't know of a way.